# Generate image from Silverlight 4 XAML on server-side without rendering UI in browser

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I'm currently trying to implement some reporting functionality which requires me to transform some Silverlight XAML content into images without the UI actually being generated on the Silverlight client.

The problem I'm trying to solve is this - how can I render the Silverlight XAML as an image without it being first displayed on the Silverlight client? The only time I've done this before was by using the WriteableBitmap API to render a currently displayed UI as an image and then converting to PNG/JPEG as appropriate. As I have the option of rendering the XAML server side, I was hoping to use WPF functionality to render the XAML - but as it's Silverlight XAML will this work?

If there's no nice way to do this, the other option as far as I can see is to try and render the UI hidden in the background of the PDF viewer Silverlight client control, pull the writeable bitmap and generate it that way - but obviously there's an overhead with this approach and it's not ideal...

Any thoughts on this appreciated, it has me scratching my head for the past couple of days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying and failing I've decided to just go with rendering the UI using GDI in on the server side.

Spent way too much time trying to force this with Silverlight, thanks for all the suggestions guys.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using the WPF runtime to render the XAML and generate a BMP from that. Typically, XAML that works in Silverlight will work in WPF, though the opposite is not always true.

WPF should let you programmatically instantiate the controls or load up loose XAML. Then you can tell it to update the layout and finally capture the visual to a bitmap.

**EDIT**

To get the xaml on the server, I'd recommend that you create a new WPF class library project in your solution. Then "Add Existing" items to that project and select to add the desired xaml files as a "linked" file, rather than copying them in. That way you can share a single file between the silverlight and the wpf projects.

Compile that DLL and use it on the server within a service or page that will return the image output. In that page, create an instance of the user control , set the datacontext, and output the image. To capture an image from a visual, you can use RenderTargetBitmap.

Here's a snippet:

```
var arrangeSize = new Size(300, 300);
var arrangeRect = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), arrangeSize);

var control = new MyControl();
control.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
control.Measure(arrangeSize);
control.Arrange(arrangeRect);
control.InvalidateVisual();
control.UpdateLayout();

RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget =
    new RenderTargetBitmap(
        arrangeSize.X,
        arrangeSize.Y,
        96,
        96,
        System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default
    );

renderTarget.Render(control);

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));

using (var pageOutStream = new FileStream(targetSavePath + ".png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    encoder.Save(pageOutStream);
    pageOutStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at doing this and see where I get. I have the UI layout and attributes in objects anyway so it should be simple enough to create the XAML in WPF... i'm just worried about incompatibilities between SL and WPF XAML

Comment: OK have found the time to have a look at this - any idea on how I can send the Silverlight XAML back to the server? XamlWriter isnt available in SL. Also, it looks like I have to render the CLR object controls in the LayoutRoot before the XAML is generated?

Comment: Added sample and reply to your question. I assume that you're not dynamically generating xaml within your silverlight solution. If that assumption is correct, the above might work. You just need to send the appropriate data back to the server so that you can instantiate the control, bind the data back into the control, and render the image.

Comment: Thanks for this Nathan - only saw your reply today so in the meantime I've been looking at doing this all in SL using a ViewBox and by adding the control objects in the codebehind. You're correct in saying that I dont generate XAML I just have a list of UIElement objects which already contain the content data I need so binding is not an issue. Having tried a WPF approach initially I had some issues with UIElement namespaces conflicting in SL and WPF. Will keep this method in the back pocket for review though, thanks!

Comment: you need third party implementation of XamlWriter, see https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r06lsr6bwh4x5a2/AABJW_KTbnDWuqkGeqtbcTzaa for various options

Answer (score 2):

An unusual request... what may suit your purpose is Chromium, and specifically some of the .Net wrappers for it. You can instantiate it in memory, render an HTML page (including Silverlight) to it, then render that out as an image (that functionality is built into the wrappers). Now this means you are still "downloading" and "rendering" the page, but you also state that doing this server side is okay.

The two Chromium wrappers that i'm familiar with are [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/download/) and [Troymium](http://www.troydesign.it/software.html). Awesomium is professionally developed and has a reasonably attractive indie licencing model, while Troymium is still in beta and is possibly not quite as mature but has a more extensive wrapper (and is currently free). Awesomium has a sample included of downloading a web page then rendering it to an image.

Note that you won't be able to use any WPF functionality, Silverlight uses a separate runtime.

Comment: Unusual request alright but a great reply, this will be my next port of call if I cant render the XAML using WPF. Cheers, will keep you updated